# Task Scheduler Script with MSOnline module

Tags: powershell

I have a PS script that runs as a scheduled task with the purpose of auditing some Active Directory criteria. I'm trying to incorporate a feature that will check if a disabled user has an E3 license assigned. The feature works while using the Powershell ISE, but not as the scheduled task.

My initial searches for this type of functionality tells me that maybe not many people have tried doing this, or the approach is not valid.

```
if (!(Get-Module -Name MSOnline)) {Import-Module MSOnline}
#Logon to O365 Tenant and query for users with an E3 license, then split their UPN discarding @domain.suffix leaving their samaccountname so I can compare with AD.
$TenantUserName = "svc-blah@blah.blah"
$TenantPassword = cat "C:\blah\PK\blah.key" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$TenantCredentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $TenantUserName, $TenantPassword
Connect-MsolService -Credential $TenantCredentials
$YE3s = Get-MsolUser -all | Where-Object {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK"} | select @{N='ADUSER';E={($_.UserPrincipalName).split('@')[0]}}
# Subsequent lines query AD for disabled users and compares $YE3s.aduser with $E3CheckDis
$DUWE3 = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $E3CheckDis.samaccountname -DifferenceObject $YE3s.aduser -IncludeEqual | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="}
#The sideline indicator "==" output is then sent to get-aduser
$ACCE3CHK = 
foreach ($DU in $DUWE3) 
{get-aduser $DU.InputObject -properties * | select Name,Distinguishedname,AccountExpirationDate,Employeetype,@{N='PwdLastSet'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.PwdLastSet)}},Mail,Enabled}
#$ACCE3CHK  is then added to a email message body as a formatted table and is sent to some individuals in the dept for corrective action.
```

The entire script works within the ISE, as I'm logged onto the system as the account doing the work, which is also the account that runs the scheduled task, but the output in the email running the task is Null.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the PowerShell/Operational event log to see if there are issues with the script as it runs?

Comment: Yes, it completes with status code of zero. I could add a write-logfile function and use try/catch, but I'm completely out of my element with that as I don't know what I'm looking to trap. A more knowledgeable person may have better insight than me.